# EXIT trap (killing background loop) not also killing processes run by that loop

Tags: bash

I am running a bash script in an environment that kills processes if no output is made within 10minutes. Therefore, I am running a background process, injecting line breaks to prevent the timeout from happening.

That works so far, but when the script has finished, it looks like the keep-alive-loop is not killed properly. The sleep command proceeds up to 590s.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Exit on any error
set -e 

# Some other commands
# ...

(while true; do echo "" && sleep 590; done) &
trap "kill $!" EXIT
ps all
looong_running_command_with_no_output
# Exit normally
```

The output of `ps` in my script:

```
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     1607    1606    1467       5032  ?         197608 20:21:05 /usr/bin/bash
     1468    1467    1467       4592  ?         197608 20:20:49 /usr/bin/bash
     1608    1607    1467       4064  ?         197608 20:21:05 /usr/bin/sleep
     1467       1    1467       4472  ?         197608 20:20:49 /usr/bin/bash
     1609    1606    1467       4768  ?         197608 20:21:05 /usr/bin/ps
     1606    1468    1467       4168  ?         197608 20:21:05 /usr/bin/bash
```

The output of `ps` after the script has finished:

```
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     1468    1467    1467       4592  ?         197608 20:20:49 /usr/bin/bash
     1637    1468    1467       2436  ?         197608 20:21:09 /usr/bin/ps
     1608       1    1467       4064  ?         197608 20:21:05 /usr/bin/sleep
     1467       1    1467       4472  ?         197608 20:20:49 /usr/bin/bash
```

You can see that sleep is still running in background. The PPID has of course changed now to 1 since it background processes get reparented to init. However, I do not understand why that happens at all. Does kill not terminate all subprocesses (sleep and echo in that case)?

**Update:** My script is running with the -e flag. Maybe that is important. I've also added the output of ps.

**Update2:**
Looks like `kill` does indeed not kill the whole process tree as mentioned in the comments. `pkill` would do, but my script runs in Git Bash where `pkill` is not available. After reading lots of posts with convoluted suggestions I ended up with the following trap:

```
trap "kill $!; wait $! 2>/dev/null; killall sleep" EXIT
```

This works well enough for my use-case.

Comment: As far as I understand the `trap` command, it will execute the first argument as soon as it receives the specified signal. In addition `$!` represents the last background process started.
Could it be, that the `$!` returns a different PID, then of your background loop?

Comment: Does `looong_running_command_with_no_output` execute any commands in the background? As presented, the code works.

Comment: @KamilCuk, yes, the long-running command is a process that spawns lots of commands. But why would that matter? Is `$!` not evaluated immediately before it is being passed as an argument to trap?

Comment: Given the use of double quotes, yes, the `$!` is evaluated *before* `trap` is invoked here.

Comment: ...and no, `kill` is not documented/guaranteed/expected to terminated the entire process tree. They'll die eventually, though, and `echo` won't be rerun if the parent shell is dead, so what's the problem?

Comment: Incidentally, it's `set -e`, not `-e` by itself.

Comment: ...also, [relying on `set -e` is a very questionable idea.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)

Comment: Theeeen... does `looong_running_command_with_no_output` change the EXIT trap? I guess in the input provided the background process had pid `1607`? it would be very strange if `bash` died without killing `sleep`.

Comment: The exit trap runs properly, I have double-checked that. It's just that `kill` does never reach the `sleep` command. The `sleep` command gets simply reparented to 1 and after it finishes, I get the message "terminated. @CharlesDuffy makes a point. I need to read what `kill` actually does and what not.

Comment: @KamilCuk, why would that be strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not as simple...

Problem is: when using `( ... )` syntax, you will create a subshell... Let's show:

In some terminal console:

```
tty
/dev/pts/24
ps --tty pts/24 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
29322 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw

( echo foo; sleep 300 ) &
[1] 30214
foo

ps --tty pts/24 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
30214 pts/24   S      0:00  \_ bash
30215 pts/24   S      0:00  |   \_ sleep 300
30377 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw

ps $!
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
30214 pts/24   S      0:00 bash
```

So `$!` is `bash` *subshell*, and `sleep` has another pid.

So killing `$!` will only kill bash:

```
kill $!
[1]+  Terminated         ( echo foo; sleep 300 )
```

but

```
ps --tty pts/24 fw
      PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
30793 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw
30215 pts/24   S      0:00 sleep 300
```

sleep is still there.

### Solution #1:

Use `exec` on last long-running command:

```
( echo foo; exec sleep 300 ) &
[1] 31557
foo

ps --tty pts/24 fw
      PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
31557 pts/24   S      0:00  \_ sleep 300
31558 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw
```

then

```
kill $!
[1]+  Terminated              ( echo foo; exec sleep 300 )

ps --tty pts/24 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
31706 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw
```

Seem ok.

### For *loop*, things are more, hem...

```
ps --tty pts/24 fw
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
 1176 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw


for ((i=3;i--;)){ sleep 300 & trap "kill $!;exit" 0 1 2 3 6 9 15;wait $!;} &
[1] 1178

ps --tty pts/24 fw
      PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
 1178 pts/24   S      0:00  \_ bash
 1179 pts/24   S      0:00  |   \_ sleep 300
 1180 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw
```

Well, now:

```
kill -1 $!
[1]+  Done                    for ((i=3; i--; 1))
do
    sleep 300 & trap "kill $!;exit" 0 1 2 3 6 9 15; wait $!;
done

ps --tty pts/24 fw
      PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
28983 pts/24   Ss     0:00 bash
 1299 pts/24   R+     0:00  \_ ps --tty pts/24 fw
```

Seem fine!

Comment: As soon as I start the long-running command with `exec`, the EXIT trap is not invoked at all.

Comment: Read my answer, I don't use `trap` in first part, where I use `exec`! `exec` will not be usefull in a loop!

Comment: I get it. Just one more question. Why does your trap subscribe to all those signals and not just to `EXIT`?

Comment: To ensure fork to be killed if script die by unnattended exceptionl...